# Camera ISO setting/ shutter speed

Tags: android, camera, iso

I am looking for a way to change the light sensitivity of my Evo 4G camerea. I know it is not the camera's shutter speed because it is a digital camera. The next most relevant aspect is the ISO setting, but the Android SDK does not have a way to manipulate it. Does any one know an alternative? i.e scene mode, exposure or effects

**parameter.set("iso", int) sets the iso.

Does anyone have the run down on what scene mode values represents?

---

Thanks for the input. I have looked over those pages numerous times. I was looking for a function similar to parameter.set("iso", int) because this function was successful in changing the iso setting. The camera does not have aperture as a setting. Maybe I can manipulate some firmware files.

Comment: _I know it is not the camera's shutter speed because it is a digital camera._ this is non-sequitur, as the shutter speed, whether mechanical or electronic (digital) when combined with the aperture setting effects the amount of light allowed to pass by the camera onto the film or sensor. This is typically referred to as exposure. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperture and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exposure_%28photography%29

Comment: +1 for non-sequitur, sure is a fancy way to tell someone they are wrong!

Answer (score 8):

Sorry it's late but might be helpful for others

To set aperture:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); 
params.set("mode", "m");
params.set("aperture", "28"); //can be 28 32 35 40 45 50 56 63 71 80 on default zoom
params.set("shutter-speed", 9); // depends on camera, eg. 1 means longest
params.set("iso", 200);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `mCamera.getParameters().flatten()` to see all the settings your camera support.

In my situation, the key of the ISO parameter is "iso-speed-values".

You can use `String isoSpeedValues = mCamera.getParameters().get("iso-speed-values")` to get all the support values.

And use `mCamera.getParameters().set("iso-speed", value)` to set a specify value.

But I can't find any parameter to set a Shutter Speed(Exposure Time). Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Try Camera.Parameter's [exposure compensation calls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation(int)).

EDIT (5/2015) Android 5.0 added APIs for this in [android.hardware.camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html). See [PkmX's lcamera](https://github.com/PkmX/lcamera) for an example.

Comment: In a sense, this parameter can change the Exposure Time， but not directly change.

Comment: True, it's an indirect effect. This has changed in Android 5.0, though - I'll update my answer.

Comment: This could be very helpful for the Camera 2 API:
[Current state of manual camera controls](http://www.camerafv5.com/pages/manual-camera-controls-table.php)