# Android 5.x Shutter Speed

Tags: android, camera2

I am trying to get supported shutter speed parameters but I am now sure how to get those ranges.

For ISO-values

String supportedIsoValues = camParams.get("iso-values"); //supported values, comma separated String
        System.out.println("supportedIsoValues: " + supportedIsoValues);

But I have no idea how to get supported shutter speed.
How can I get a supported shutter speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with [Camera](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) from Android Devs. They tell us that starting with API 21 you should move over to [android.hardware.camera2.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) There is a lot you can [ask from a camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html), it seems. Very informative, but not the answer you are looking for.

This [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550136/camera-iso-setting-shutter-speed/3550573#3550573) post's answer has the answer(s) you want.

To be complete, here is [PkmX's lcamera's](https://github.com/PkmX/lcamera) example for the kind of codes you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Even "iso-values" is not part of the standard Android camera API - it's a (common) vendor extension, and can't be relied on to be present.

There's no official support for either ISO or exposure time control in the old, deprecated camera API.  You need to move to camera2 for that, and check that the device supports capability [MANUAL_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR).

Then you can disable AE, and manually control exposure time, frame duration, and ISO sensitivity.