# How to control shutter manually in android. camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2, shutter

I want to control the shutter using camera 2. but I have no idea how to control shutter in camera preview manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 5.x Shutter Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300124/android-5-x-shutter-speed)

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to control?