# Android app development set camera exposure time

Tags: android

I m currently working on an application for a colorimetric assay.
I am using the Galaxy J3V in-built Camera application to capture images, however, my problem is I can not disable the Autoexposure function and control the exposure time.  I am using Image-Cropper 2.6.0 for image capture and cropping (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and I have read the following post: [Camera ISO setting/ shutter speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550136/camera-iso-setting-shutter-speed)

How do I use this code in my case? 
Android studio error red highlight says "can not resolve symbol camera" when I copy&past the code underneath

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

Here is the code:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters(); 

params.set("mode", "m");
params.set("aperture", "28"); //can be 28 32 35 40 45 50 56 63 71 80 on default zoom
params.set("shutter-speed", 9); // depends on camera, eg. 1 means longest
params.set("iso", 200);
```

In short, I want to disable autoexposure and fix exposure time (fix shutter speed and aperture et al ) everytime I open the camera.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You Can check this out.

setExposureCompensation sets exposure to the camera

```
Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMaxExposureCompensation());
mCamera.setParameters(params);
mCamera.startPreview();
```

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Comment: It is the Camera Object reference